# OIDC configuration for Terraform/GitLab CI in a multi-account context

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, gitlab

I wrote some Terraform code. I logged in locally using AWS Identity Center so that I would not have to generate IAM access and secret keys (as per AWS's good practice recommendations).

I'm going to prod soon, so I'm prepping the CD process. Identity Center login goes out the window as the SSO login is not something that can be easily automated. Enters OIDC integration: instead of using credentials I'm using a token in the CI/CD pipeline.

OIDC configuration naturally means you need to attach your least-privileged permissions policy. The problem is: my Terraform code targets multiple AWS accounts.

What would be best in this context: to setup as many OIDC integrations as accounts I am using, or to build a unique policy that targets the different accounts?